# UIPickerView Delegate/DataSource in separate class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am developing an iPhone application. And I have a common UIPickerView falls throughout the app (With same data) . I was just wondering whether I could have UIPickerView delegate methods and datasource methods in a separate class (Make it a common one) . When I hit the class it should return a UIPickerView with values loaded.

I am not using XIB files. Is there a way to do this?!

Thanks in advance!! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes , you can do this . Like this:

1) Declare a class that implements the delegate methods.

2) Declare a class that implements the datasource methods. (Can be the same class from step 1  . In fact I suggest you do it like this.)

3) When you alloc an `UIPickerView` create an object of type class_from_step1 and set it as your picker's delegate

4) When you alloc an `UIPickerView` create an object of type class_from_step2 and set it as your picker's datasource

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey George! Thanks for the quick response :-) I did the same even before asking the question!! Actually I created the UIPickerView in the same class where I set delegate and datasource methods. I was so stupid!! It is not possible at all, right?!

Comment: That is posible. If I understand correctly , you are doing this: `UIPickerView *picker = alloc , init , set delegate:self , set` `datasource:self etc ; [self.view addSubview:picker];` . Right? That is not a problem if self is a `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDatasource` and if it implements the `@required` methods from these protocols.

Comment: Whoa!! Can you explain me about the @required methods? That is what exactly I was doing. Instead of adding it in self.view, I added it on a temporary view and returned that view!!

Comment: When you declare that your class is implementing a protocol ( like for  instance in your .h file you have <UIPickerViewDelegate> next to your class name. If you go to the definition of that protocol you will see that some of the methods in the protocol are @ required and some are @ optional. If you implement a protocol , you have to implement all of the @ required methods of that protocol. It's somehow similar to the @ public and @private access specifiers.

Comment: Oh!! I got it!! :-) Would try it some other time in my application! :-) Its working perfect now!! Thank You!! :-)